# Cordova app triggering game mode in Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: android, cordova

Currently making a cordova app which I'm testing in samsung galaxy s8. However, whenever I open it it triggers the game mode/game launcher. I was wondering what's causing it. Is there something I have to edit in the config.xml to have it consider as a regular app?

Comment: any news? I have the same problem!

Comment: @r1si I had setup a new cordova app and moved www files. Now it's okay. Not really sure what the difference is. Could be the meta tags in the index.html file? 
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Cordova v8.0.0:

You need to change the default package name in `config.xml` from:

`io.cordova.hellocordova`

to your own, for example:

`com.yourcompanyname.yourappname`

Related to:
[Non-game App gets treated as game by Samsung game launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174122/non-game-app-gets-treated-as-game-by-samsung-game-launcher)