# Non-game App gets treated as game by Samsung game launcher

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Whenever I open my android app it triggers the game mode/game launcher on samsung galaxy s8. But the app isn't a game. In a previous version the app used opengl and it seems like samsung treats an app as game if it uses opengl. I already removed the opengl code but samsung still treats the app as game. The strange thing is when I change the application-id the app launches normally. So, I think samsung stores the application-id as game somewhere. Anyone ever had a similar problem with samsung game launcher?

Comment: Were you able to solve it ? I am the creator for Videoder , an app which has over 50 million installs and suddenly today game launcher started treating my app as a game :(

Comment: I have the same issue, My app also behaves like a game in Samsung device. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: This Samsung Game Launcher really is a piece of s**t. It makes Samsung J3 devices reboot randomly while playing my game. And there is no way to disable this bloat without root!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Yeah for my it was the application-id , but I have no idea who to contact to have it removed from Samsungs System.

Answer (score 7):

this problem happens if the package name is "com.exmaple" only Samsung detect it as game i do not know why, 
after i change the package name to "com.exmaple.android" it worked fine.

Comment: god, bless you, dude. I've wasted so many hours by trying to fix this issue and nothing worked. Thank you.

Comment: how can you change the package name? according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play it is not possible to change the package name once it is published

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and I resolved it by changing `app.json` package to something like

```
...
"android": {
  "package": "com.youruniquecompanyname.yourappname"
},
...
```

Comment: Where is app.json?

Comment: "android" key on that object

Comment: our app package name is net.companyname.appname, and it is still treated as a game by Samsung game launcher.

Answer (score 1):

To offer the best experience to the users, Samsung Galaxy devices have diverse processes and services. As a part of that, Games are recognized and categorized under the "Game Launcher" service on Samsung Galaxy devices to be well catered and managed.

Generally, this categorization is done based on the application category registered on the app stores. If the app (package id) is registered or enlisted as a game in any store, it's recognized and categorized as a game. That's the general procedure, but this categorization can be erroneous.

If your application is categorized as a game while not being a game app at all, please reach [Samsung Developers Site > Support > Developer Support](https://developer.samsung.com/dev-support) with the details:

- Your application's use case and why it should not be categorized as a Game.
- Package-id and content-id of your application.

You would get proper and rapid support from Samsung there.

Answer (score 0):

this can be fixed in the google play services if i'm not mistaken you should check there at this time i'm actually a bit busy maybe when done i can check please more info about your problem

Comment: Thanks Tony, yes I use google play services by adding them like this to my build.gradle file: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'. What do you think is causing this specifically? Searching the project for the term "game" returns the following package in a generated R.java file: com.google.android.gms.games. Do you think this has something to do with this issue?

Comment: this is certainly the issue  com.google.android.gms<there should be something here to define the API you are about to use >:play-services:11.6.0.... your app is taking it as a game ...i can't give you a solution due to not knowing what is it that you are doing or what you actually want .... apparently you  are scared of showing your source code therefore  try finding a solution about this here: https://developers.google.com/s/results/?q=com.google.android.gms%3Aplay-services%3A11.6.0&p=%2Fandroid%2F

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova v8.0.0:

You need to change the default package name in `config.xml` from:

`io.cordova.hellocordova`

to your own, for example:

`com.yourcompanyname.yourappname`

Answer (score 0):

I detect this happend when you use gaming mode.. try switch to balance mode.. it happend to me yesterday.. i still use gaming mode just turn off the lock & notifocation.. when gaming i turn on back.. oh yah im using samsung note 5..

Answer (score 0):

this seems to happen on samsung phones due to the package name. since we cant change this after the first release, you must contact samsung developer support and they can fix it. i wrote a gist on github about it:

https://gist.github.com/Adnan-Bacic/718eb3b4e70380696c91dc21c4804112

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a simple way to mark an app as "not a game" to keep it out of game launcher. I can't find it now.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33805369)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).