# Samsung game launcher detects non-game apps as games

Tags: android, google-play-games, samsung-mobile

My application does not have any games inside but unfortunately samsung game launcher detects the app as game and hide the icon. the only way to open the app is through samsung game launcher.
why and how does samsung game launcher detects app as game?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174122/non-game-app-gets-treated-as-game-by-samsung-game-launcher), try changing app.json package to something like:

> ```
> "android": {
>       "package": "com.youruniquecompanyname.yourappname"
>   },
> ```

You may also check this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOUqz.jpg) for additional workaround.

Comment: where is exactly app.json file?