# My app is recognized as a game on Samsung devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

There was no problem in the development phase of my application, but after it was uploaded to the Play Store, I started having problems.

When I open the application, Game Booster mode automatically opens on the Samsung Galaxy series.

Where should I define that my app is not a game? Play Store, Samsung Support or code?

By the way, my app is not in the game category in the Play Store.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBRiu.png

Comment: DOes it use OpenGL?  That seems to be the most likely way for it to recognize it.  But I don't believe Samsung actually publishes how that works, so you're only going to get guesses.

Comment: Possible dubplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174122/non-game-app-gets-treated-as-game-by-samsung-game-launcher